Acquiring access token while using .http files
I use Azure AD B2C for identity management and want to use .http files for testing my API. Is there an easy way to acquire access_token from Azure AD B2C directly from the .http file?
I currently have to use my web or .NET MAUI app to do an actual login and then grab the access_token from my code that uses it and this is a cumbersome process. It would be very nice if there was a way to handle all this in the .http file.

For testing scenarios, you'd use a client_credentials client-registration (so you'd be using only OAuth2 features and not using OIDC); if your application requires or expects OIDC "human" Claims in JWTs that aren't in OAuth2 then you need to manually add them as hardcoded claims to the client-registration. But if it also depends on id_token  being present then you'll need to do things the hard-way (i.e. emulate a web-browser using HttpClient that completes the code/PKCE process).
